# 8 - How can I update the entity reference fields of the form when I close the modal?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax, modal-dialogs

How can I update the entity reference fields of the form based on selection in the modal dialog when I close the modal ?

I have a form and users starts fill the form.
Then click on choose address button, opens modal dialog box.
After selection I need to close the modal dialog and update the form data based on selection.

Any suggestions would be great.
Thanks.